# <form action> the requested resource is not available with servlet

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets

Try to run an example: [Click here](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/servlet/RadioButton.html)

Go to RadioButton.html. It works fine.

But when I confirm the dish, I get "The requested resource is not available (404)" in Apache Tomcat 7. The page redirects me to localhost:8080/content/RadioButton?dish=Russian (page RadioButton.html is located in folder content, but servlet RadioButton is located in src folder) instead of `localhost:8080/RadioButton?dish=Russian`
All the problem I see in form method="get" action="RadioButton".

Comment: You have to correct your `action="demo_form.asp"`-part. It's pointing to the wrong location. Maybe it's `action="src/demo_form.asp"` ?

Comment: what is your root url?

Comment: Here is my project: http://pixs.ru/showimage/1png_4135055_10694411.png

Comment: which ide you are using? eclipse?

Comment: maja, action="src/RadioButton" redirects me to localhost:8080/content/src/RadioButton?dish=Italian

Comment: can you show your folder hieredchy

Comment: java seeker, I use IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: java seeker, if you mean my project, then it is here http://pixs.ru/showimage/1png_4135055_10694411.png, if you mean OS, then C:\Users\zer0\IdeaProjects\geek\FileManager. FileManager contains folders "src", "web". "src" contains *.java files, "web" contains folders "content" (with RadioButton.html), "WEB-INF" and file index.jsp. All compiled classes located in C:\Users\zer0\IdeaProjects\geek\out\artifacts\FileManager_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes and C:\Users\zer0\IdeaProjects\geek\out\production\FileManager

Comment: Thanks for the valuable inputs. I had to change the location of RadioButtom.html to web directory where index.jsp is located and it worked for me.